# need to get group by data using join/subQuery on multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have table **lookup** with columns **trackingId** and **string**

| **trackingId** | **string** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | QQ |
| 3 | we |
| 2 | QQ |
| 4 | rt |
| . | .. |
| . | .. |
| . | .. |

```
select trackingId from lookup where string = 'QQ'
```

I need to use output of this query in table - **content_item**. content_item follow below

| **content_id** | **tracking_id** | **approval_status** | **date** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | AP | 2014 |
| 102 | 1 | PN | 2016 |
| 103 | 3 | PN | 2015 |
| 104 | 4 | AP | 2018 |
| 105 | 2 | RJ | 2019 |
| 106 | 4 | PN | 2019 |
| 107 | 5 | PN | 2019 |
| 108 | 6 | RJ | 2019 |
| ... | . | .. | .... |

I want to group this data by date
my output should be like

| **year** | **count** |
| --- | --- |
| 2014 | 1 |
| 2019 | 3 |
| .... | . |

means in each group tracing ids should be unique.
(if one tracking id is counted in one group then it should not be counted in any other group)

- Also data of tracking id 3 and 4 should not be counted (b'z I only want data for string QQ).

Please let me know if this is doable. any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Comment: How did you get that output? For QQ, tracking id of 1 shows up in 2016 as well, and there is only one instance of QQ (the 2) in 2019. Please tag what database you're using (sql server? mysql? oracle?) and be more specific as to what you think your output should be, given the sample data you posted.

Comment: @Nikki9696 to you question (For QQ, tracking id of 1 shows up in 2016 as well) -> thats the requirement, as trackingId 1 is already counted in group of 2014, it should not be count in any further groups.
 (there is only one instance of QQ (the 2) in 2019) -> I just mentioned 4 rows in lookup, it may have many rows. from the output (3 count for 2019) means trackingId 5 and 6 also have QQ
Database - sysbase

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` the tables to get the `'QQ'` content_items. Then `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` the rows:

```
select c.date, count(*)
from content_item c
  join lookup l on c.tracking_id = l.tracking_id
where l.string = 'QQ'
group by c.date
```

Comment: as I understand from this query,  count will contains duplicate trackingIds.
trackingIds should be different. (if any tracking ids is counted in any group, it should not be counted in any other group)

Comment: Does the expected result really match the sample data?